# Not able to get mails from a certain folder in outlook in the order of their received date

Tags: python, outlook, mapi

> python

```
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder=outlook.Folders.Item("required folder")
mails=folder.Items
mail=mails.GetLast()
while(mail):
   print(mail.SentOn)
   mail=mails.GetPrevious()
```

not getting the mails in the order of their received date

> output:

```
2019-10-27 07:54:44+00:00
2019-10-27 07:55:46+00:00
2019-10-25 14:17:07+00:00
2019-10-23 10:06:08+00:00
2019-10-24 09:33:07+00:00
2019-10-25 02:59:24+00:00
```

why the output is not in the order of their received date?
while the mails in the outlook are in the order of their received date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no order unless you explicitly call `Items.Sort`. Most likely you will get the items in their creation date, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: i'm using GetLast() for the latest mail and going through using GetPrevious() right?
why wouldn't i get the mails in order?

Comment: GetLast does not mean "the latest received item". It means the last in the sort order set by a call to Sort. If you do not call Sort, you get some default undefined order.

Comment: yeah
fine for mails
but 
what if i wanted to sort folders in the order of their existance

Comment: Do you mean in the order displayed by Outlook? Note that the Folders collection in OOM does not have the Sort method.

Comment: If the reply answers your *original* question, please mark it as such. If you have a new question, start a new thread.